# PHP translation From SQL Database

Tags: javascript, php, sql

My site pulls test questions from a database, and some of these questions have images associated with them.

The images pull in fine and everything works as expected, but when trying to pull the answers for these questions, which sometimes also have images, there is a translation issue causing just the reference index to be called and no image displayed (the text still appears that is associated with the answer however).

[Question Picture Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZFPY.png)

[Answer Picture Example - An image should appear in the highlighted area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07Fbm.png)

I can't tell if the issue is caused in the HTML/PHP interpretation of calling an answer or in the function that defines the answer to be called. Code snippets below.
First is the HTML/PHP and JS. All things pertaining to answers are "Rationale" All things pertaining to images are "equations":

```
<?php
            for ($i = 0; $i < $displayCount; $i++) {
                $workingDate = date('Y-m-d', time()-($i*24*60*60));
                $QID = updateQOTD($ar, $workingDate, $level);
                $questionInfo = getQuestion($ar, $QID);
                echo $workingDate."<br><br>";
                if(isset($questionInfo->VIGNETTE)) {
                    echo "<strong>Vignette</strong>:<br>";
                    echo $questionInfo->VIGNETTE;
                    echo "<br><br>";
                }
                $equation = getEquation($ar, $QID);
                $eq_text = '';
                if (isset($equation)) {
                $file = $equation->FILE_NAME;
                $eq_text = '<img src="/lcms/images/equations/' . $file . '">';
                }
                                    echo "<strong>Question</strong>:<br><br>";

                $qtext = $questionInfo->TEXT ;
                $qtext = preg_replace('/<equation id="\d+"\/>/', $eq_text, $qtext);
                echo $qtext;
                echo "<br><br>"; 
                
                ?>
                <div id='response_<?php echo $i; ?>'></div>
                <div class='rationale margin-top-20'><br><strong>Rationale:</strong><br>
                            <?php echo $questionInfo->RATIONALE; ?>
                            </div>
                        <?php
                        }
                        ?>
                        <button id="grade" class="btn-theme" type="button">Grade My Choices</button>
<? require_once(getenv("DOCUMENT_ROOT")."/inc/footer.pilot.php"); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".rationale").hide();
        $("response_1").hide();
        $("response_2").hide();
        $("response_3").hide();
        $("response_4").hide();
        $("response_5").hide();
        $("#grade").click(function () {
            $(".correctMark").html("<img src='../../images/600px-Green_check.png' />");
            $(".incorrectMark").html("<img src='../../images/600px-Red_x.png' />");
            $(".rationale").slideDown("fast");

            if ($("input[name='question_1']:checked").val() == 'correct') {
                $("#response_1").text("Your answer was correct!");
                $("#response_1").slideDown("slow");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

And here is the database code call SQL and function defining Rationale:

```
function getEquation($ar, $QID) {
    if (isset($QID) && $QID > 0) {
        $selectSql = sprintf("SELECT e.FILE_NAME FROM equation_tbl e, equation_question_link_tbl eq WHERE eq.QUESTION_ID = %s AND e.ID = eq.EQUATION_ID ",
            $QID);
        $equation = $ar->get_row($selectSql);

        return $equation;
    }
}

function getQuestion($ar, $QID) {
    $selectSql = sprintf("SELECT case_tbl.TEXT as VIGNETTE, question_tbl.TEXT, question_tbl.ANSWER_1, question_tbl.ANSWER_2, question_tbl.ANSWER_3, question_tbl.ANSWER_4, question_tbl.ANSWER_5, question_tbl.ANSWER_6, question_tbl.ANSWER_7, question_tbl.ANSWER_8, question_tbl.RATIONALE FROM question_tbl LEFT JOIN case_tbl ON question_tbl.CASE_ID = case_tbl.ID WHERE question_tbl.ID = %s",
        $QID);
        
    $question = $ar->get_row($selectSql);
    return $question;
}

function makeAnswerArray($questionInfo) {
    $answers[0] = array($questionInfo->ANSWER_1, 'correct');
    $answers[1] = array($questionInfo->ANSWER_2, 'incorrect');
    $answers[2] = array($questionInfo->ANSWER_3, 'incorrect');
    if(isset($questionInfo->ANSWER_4) && $questionInfo->ANSWER_4 > ' ') {
        $answers[3] = array($questionInfo->ANSWER_4, 'incorrect');
        if(isset($questionInfo->ANSWER_5) && $questionInfo->ANSWER_5 > ' ') {
            $answers[4] = array($questionInfo->ANSWER_5, 'incorrect');
            if(isset($questionInfo->ANSWER_6) && $questionInfo->ANSWER_6 > ' ') {
                $answers[5] = array($questionInfo->ANSWER_6, 'incorrect');
                if(isset($questionInfo->ANSWER_7) && $questionInfo->ANSWER_7 > ' ') {
                    $answers[6] = array($questionInfo->ANSWER_7, 'incorrect');
                    if(isset($questionInfo->ANSWER_8) && $questionInfo->ANSWER_8 > ' ') {
                        $answers[7] = array($questionInfo->ANSWER_8, 'incorrect');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $answers;
}
```

Is there any reason why the images associated with Rationales are not pulling through when expected?

Comment: hi, is this an html field?

Comment: without access to some kind of test link it'd be nearly impossible to solve your problem...

what happens to the image? does it not show the tag on the html? does it show the tag but the image is returning 404?

Answer (score 0):

I would start by checking the values of `$equation` with `var_dump($equation)` and also `var_dump($question)` to look for any anomalies. I suspect you've got incomplete data creeping in that looks like `/lcms/images/equations/NULL` or something similar which should be obvious enough, when dumped.

If this is the case, look at extending your handling of these vars to be more strict about the expected value.

Truth be told, it's going to be difficult to help if we cannot run the code. But I would start by checking data integrity of the MySQL result. Bit of a SQL join in there too that only you will know the correct format of, which would be my next port of call.